# Filter database table/query whilst typing in TEdit box

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firedac

I have a form which has a cxGrid on it and connects to a database table via TADQuery (FireDAC).

I've also added a TEdit box to the same form. When a user starts typing into the TEdit box, can I make the grid start to filter the results based on what the user is typing (preferably for more than one field in the table)?

If so, your thoughts/examples would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware that cxGrid has built-in filtering support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `FDQuery`, you might have a sort of query like this :

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE ColumnA LIKE :paramA
```

This would apply to a string column, but any other logical comparison would work.  I presume you know how to write your query.

You would of course need to add the parameter, either programmatically or via the `Parameters` property in the design-time Object Inspector, being sure to match the parameter's name with that used in the query.  I presume also that you know how to do this.

In the `OnChange` handler of your `TEdit`, then, you could do something like:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDQuery1.Params.ParamByName('paramA').Value := Format('%%%s%%',[Edit1.Text]);
  FDQuery1.Refresh;
end;
```

This, naturally, braces the search term with `%` SQL wildcards, narrowing the returned records to those which contain the substring typed by the user into the edit box.

If you are querying a large dataset where the `.Refresh` operation is long-running you can instead use a timer to delay refreshing the dataset until the user has stopped typing for a given interval of time.

Answer (score 1):

Use the KeyDown event in the TEdit Field to start a timer. With the Timer-Event you check if the Text is still changing (User is still typing) - A Intervall for the timer of maybe 500 ms - 1 sek is engough between the checks. 
If the Text did not change in the meantime requery your cxGrid using the Text in the Edit-Field. On top of this you could use a thread to requery your Grid.
The slower the user types and the lager the Table you are quering the longer your intervall should be.

Answer (score 0):

Better use filter

```
procedure TForm4.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
 if trim(edit1.Text)>'' then
 begin
   adoquery1.Filter:='field1 like '+quotedstr(trim(edit1.Text)+'%');
   adoquery1.Filtered:=true
 end
 else      adoquery1.Filtered:=false
```

end;

Comment: Not necessarily better if a parameterised query (as in the accepted answer) retrieves only a small proportion of the rows of a large table.